# net.show command only shows my own ip not other devices

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I am running kali linux with vmware and when i use bettercap's net.show it only shows eth0 and gateway and it doesnt show all the devices connected to the network.

I did try turning net.probe on and i changed the vm settings to bridging but it still doesnt work,
any ideas how i can get other devices ips?┌────────────────┬───────────────────┬─────────┬───────────────────────┬───────┬───────┬──────────┐

│      IP ▴      │        MAC        │  Name   │        Vendor         │ Sent  │ Recvd │   Seen   │

├────────────────┼───────────────────┼─────────┼───────────────────────┼───────┼───────┼──────────┤

│ 172.21.187.177 │ 00:0c:29:b7:40:54 │ eth0    │ VMware, Inc.          │ 0 B   │ 0 B   │ 16:41:03 │

│ 172.21.176.1   │ 00:15:5d:36:70:61 │ gateway │ Microsoft Corporation │ 150 B │ 85 B  │ 16:41:04 │

│                │                   │         │                       │       │       │